# How to write an effective but gentle reminder email to a journal editor?

Tags: publications

I have received an acceptance email of my article from editor in August-2015 and I was told that my article  will be published in their issue of XXXXX 2015/2016. Meanwhile one issue of the journal is published in january-2016 without my article and the next issue is expected in May-2016. Now I am going to write a reminder email mentioning to consider my article for publication in the forthcoming issue. Please guide me or share some gentle format, so that I may be able to communicate with editor well in time.

Answer (score 25):

**Make it a question, not a reminder.**

I see no particular reason to worry that your paper has been forgotten. It seems more likely just that yours is scheduled for the May issue (or later in the year) because there were enough earlier-submitted articles to fill up the January issue.

On the other hand, asking politely “Roughly when should I expect my paper to appear?” is a completely reasonable question — there are many reasons you might want to know it — and contains no implied criticism that an editor might take offence at.

And in case the editor *has* forgotten your paper, this will have the desired effect of a reminder anyway.

Comment: From many experiences, asking questions of this type as if I had forgotten something (instead of as if the other person forgot something) are always better received. "I can't seem to find the original acceptance email you sent me for [Acrticle XYZ] last year. Could you give me an idea which upcoming issue it will appear in?" is much more polite than "You said my paper would be published by now. Where is it?"

Answer (score 8):

How about this :-)

Dear [Insert journal editor’s name]:

This is with regard to my/our accepted manuscript, [Insert manuscript reference number], titled “[Insert manuscript title],” submitted to your journal on [Insert date of submission].

We have not received an update regarding the publishing status of our manuscript. Could you let us know when we can expect notice regarding the time and the issue it will be published in?

Thank you for your time and consideration. We look forward to hearing from you.

Sincerely,

[Insert author name and correspondence details]

Comment: Of-course more feasible one.